# How to generate PDF from HTML and add link reference(any website) in java code?

Tags: java, itext

I am facing an issue related to generate a PDF file from HTML.
In HTML code, I want to click on image and link to "www.w3schoo.com"
but current I can not do that. When done generate that link are not able to click.

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        XMLParser xmlParser;
        try {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D://temp/test-st.pdf"));
            document.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            document.open();

            CSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(false);
            HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
            htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

            PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
            HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
            CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);
            XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
            xmlParser = new XMLParser(worker);

            xmlParser.parse(new StringReader("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n" +
                    "<html>\n" +
                    "<head>\n" +
                    "    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\n" +
                    "    <link href=\"page.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n" +
                    "</head>\n" +
                    "<body>\n" +
                    "<p>HELLO WORLD</p>\n" +
                    "<a href = \"https://www.w3schools.com/\"> CLICK HERE TO LINk TO W3SCHOOL</a>\n" +
                    "</body>\n" +
                    "</html>"));
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is out put
[image]

You can see my picture here.
I can not click to link w3school.
It seem href not working when parsing to PDF.

I am able to click image and link to any website If I do this.

```
    Image image = Image.getInstance("C://temp/sample.png");
    Chunk chunk = new Chunk(image,0,0,false);
    Anchor anchor = new Anchor(chunk);
    anchor.setReference("https://www.w3schools.com/");
    document.add(anchor);
```

But in case, I read HTML code to generate PDF.
Please kindly help me with this issue?
Thank you!!

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. **I already need your support.** isnt a clear problem statement you see.

Comment: Hi @James. Your updated code still has spaces around the equal sign of the href attribute. You should replace this part `"<a href = \"https://www.w3schools.com/\">` with `"<a href=\"https://www.w3schools.com/\">`. Here is [the result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_YqAB7Dk2GDoWeu4DdDsWDlbsXbYf6Hv/view?usp=sharing) when you remove the spaces around the href.

Comment: Hi @MohamedAMAZIRH. Thank you so much. Now it's working:)

Comment: Glad to have been of help. You can accept the answer now since it worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

The spaces around the equal sign in `<a href = "https://www.w3schools.com/" >` are preventing the itextpdf from parsing the href attribute correctly.

And don't forget `document.close()` after

> xmlParser.parse(new StringReader(htmlFile));

Here is the code I used to reproduce the issue:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.html.Tags;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CSSResolver;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.end.PdfWriterPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipeline;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.pipeline.html.HtmlPipelineContext;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        XMLParser xmlParser;
        try {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("/tmp/test-st.pdf"));
            //document.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            document.open();


            CSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(false);
            HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
            htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

            PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
            HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
            CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);
            XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
            xmlParser = new XMLParser(worker);

            xmlParser.parse(new StringReader("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n" +
                    "<html>\n" +
                    "<head>\n" +
                    "    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />\n" +
                    "    <link href=\"page.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />\n" +
                    "</head>\n" +
                    "<body>\n" +
                    "<p>HELLO WORLD</p>\n" +
                    "<a href = \"https://www.w3schools.com/\" >\n" +
                    "<img src=\"images/abc.jpg\" alt=\"Testing\"/> Test Test\n" +
                    "</a>\n" +
                    "</body>\n" +
                    "</html>"));
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: No I can reproduce the issue (with some modification the code provided). I'll update my answer to add the code I used

Comment: Be careful about spending so much time on such stuff though. It is the OPs responsibility to provide a real MCVE. But kudos for spending that time here!

Comment: Thanks. I was definitely going to add a comment to request more information if it took too much time to reproduce the problem with the provided code. I hope he'll update the description if he finds that the answer works for him.

Comment: Hello @MohamedAMAZIRH, thank for your answer, but href attribute still not working.
is there anyway to solved this issue?

Comment: hello @GhostCat, I have update my question, it maybe easily for you to understand my question. And thank for your time for answer and feedback me